# select child div with nth-child and apply hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to get nth-child to work on a set of divs and then apply `hover` pseudo to it:

```
<div class="uk-home-button">
    <div>
        <div class="uk-panel-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="uk-panel-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="uk-panel-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="uk-panel-box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

heres what i thought i could do

```
.uk-home-button div.uk-panel-box:nth-child(1):hover{background-color:#2980b9;}
```

But instead of selecting div 1, it applies the css to all four divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the hover effect on the first box, use this selector:

```
.uk-home-button div:nth-child(1) .uk-panel-box:hover {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBKXQw

It selects the `.uk-panel-box` inside the first child div of the outer container (`.uk-home-button div:nth-child(1)`)

Comment: Thank you worked brilliantly, didnt think of adding the `.uk-panel-box:hover` after the `nth-child` .

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   div > div > div:hover {
>     background: red;
>   }
> ```

This means: Find a div that has a div parent (mom) and that parent has a parent (grandma). Using the direct descendant selector `>` insures a rigidly specific hierarchy that narrows down to the deepest nested div only while the mom and grandma are ignored.

When you use `nth` selectors such as `child` and `of-type` we must keep these things in mind:

1. `nth`s are concerned about an element's position among it's siblings.
2. `nth`s are concerned about an element's tag (i.e. `<a>`, `<div>`, `<li>`).
3. `nth`s ignore anything else: class, id, attributes, etc.
4. `nth`s will apply it's rules to **everything** it pertains to (i.e. 3 divs one inside the other, all 3 divs would be affected by `div:first-child`.)
5. When counting siblings, `nth-child` types will count all siblings, and `nth-of-type` will count all siblings with the same tag.

#### SNIPPET

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.uk-panel-box {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  border-color: orange;
}
.uk-home-button {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  border-color: blue;
}
div > div > div:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="uk-home-button">
  <div>
    <div class="uk-panel-box"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="uk-panel-box"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="uk-panel-box"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="uk-panel-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
.uk-home-button > div:nth-child(1):hover { }
```

You need the *direct descendant* selector (`>`) as your `.uk-panel-box` divs are all also first children of their parents (the non-classed divs). Hence, you need the first div which is the *direct* first child of `.uk-home-button`.

```css
.uk-home-button > div:nth-child(1):hover {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}
```

```html
<div class="uk-home-button">
  <div>
    <div class="uk-panel-box">1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="uk-panel-box">2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="uk-panel-box">3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="uk-panel-box">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the advice, i had amended the original question, as i think the issue is the divs are nested in another div.